# Не работает чат на node.js

Tags: php, node.js, чат

Мне нужен чат на node.js и apache(php), я вроде во всём уже разобрался, но работать почему-то не хочет, прошу помочь.
Сервер:

```
    var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(8081, function(){
  console.log('listening on:8081');
});
```

Клиент:

```
    $(function () {
        var socket = io();
        socket.connect('https://php-justrelaxdc.c9users.io:8081');
      $('#form').submit(function(){
        if($('#sendMassage').val() != ''){
          socket.emit( 'chat message', $('#sendMassage').val() );
          $('#sendMassage').val('');
          return false;
      }else{
          return false;
      }
    });
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
      $('.chat ul').append("<li class='<?php echo $visitor ?>'>" + text(msg) + "</li>");
      var div = $(".chat");
      div.scrollTop(div.prop('scrollHeight'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Что значит "_не хочет работать_"? Выпадает с ошибкой, происходит что-то, чего вы не ожидали или вообще ничего не происходит?

Comment: Не происходит вообще ничего, в консоль переодически само по себе выкидывает ошибку `GET https://php-justrelaxdc.c9users.io/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LzZnb6V 404 (Not Found)`. Хотя js код работает, потому что когда нажимаю "Отправить", то поле отчищается.

Comment: Для начала, вам стоит использовать модуль `https`, а не `http`. А дальше вам таки придется локализовать проблему, потому что сейчас она не воспроизводится.

Comment: Начал использовать https, поставил вместо `var socket = io();
        socket.connect('https://php-justrelaxdc.c9users.io:8081');` -> `var socket = io.connect('localhost:8081', {'transports': ['xhr-polling']});`. Ошибку выбивать перестало, но ничего не работает, сделал чтоб выводило сообщение при коннекте, но тоже ничего не выводит. Мне кажется проблема в том, что я не правильно хост указываю что ли... Я уже по-разному пробовал